# What is the pythonic way to handle accessing json values without knowing whether an index exists?

Tags: python, json

The parameters I'm passing to a constructor are from a json object and occasionally get an `IndexError: list index out of range`

```
class ApiResponse(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

apiResponse =  ApiResponse(
    a = jsonResponse['foo']['bar']['a'],
    b = jsonResponse['bar']['foo']['b']
)
```

If the index `jsonResponse['foo']['bar']['a']` does not exists, I just want the default value of `None` to be set in the object (ie, I do not want to pass an argument for `a` to the constructor.)

Is there a succinct way to do this (I have about 8 parameters in my class and the arguments are sourced from varying dimensions of the json object)?

Comment: One solution: https://github.com/NYTimes/safejson

Comment: Why don't you handle it through the exceptions?

Comment: Succinct, but I think not very pythonic (therefore not an answer): `a = reduce(lambda d, k: d.get(k, {}), ['foo', 'bar', 'a'], jsonResponse)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, JSON data can be represented as dictionaries and they have a `get` method which accept a default value, if the key is not found. You can chain them like this

```
apiResponse =  ApiResponse(
    a = jsonResponse.get('foo', {}).get('bar', {}).get('a', None),
    b = jsonResponse.get('bar', {}).get('foo', {}).get('b', None)
)
```

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know get could be used this way :)

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks!  One question, what if my json object has a list like this `jsonResponse.get('foo', {})[1].get('a', None)`?  If the list does not exist I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`.  Is there a simple way I can account for these cases?

Comment: @user784637 You can circumvent that, like this `jsonResponse.get('foo', [None, {}])[1].get('a', None)` :)

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting an error `IndexError: list index out of range` when I use that syntax

Comment: @user784637 Does the `jsonResponse['foo']` has atleast two elements?

Comment: @thefourtheye In the use case where the index is out of range `jsonResponse['foo']` is a list with 0 elements, but usually it has 1 element, and that element is a dictionary.

Comment: @user784637 Actually, if we put all the logic in a single line, the code will become difficult to manage. Can you please have this check explicitly?

Comment: @thefourtheye sure, what do you mean by "check explicitly" though?

Comment: `if len(jsonResponse.get('foo', [])) >= 2: jsonResponse["foo"][1].get('a', None)`